# My class autoload function is not working in my mvc

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, autoloader

MVC uploaded on cloud9, but when the auto-load class located in `lib/init.php` is not working. The `.htaccess` in the project folder or webroot folder files are not properly configured.

When I visit my project link https://my-mvc-hunteelar.c9users.io/ it gives this exception :

> **Failed to load class:** Config' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/init.php on line 21

I have 2 `.htaccess` files. The first .htaccess code in the main project folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The second `.htaccess` file located in the webroot folder which is supposed to be the public folder of my MVC:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
```

The `init.php` code which contains the `__autoload` function.

```
require_once (ROOT.DS.'config'.DS.'config.php');
function __autoload($class_name){

    $lib_path = ROOT.DS.'lib'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'class.php';
    $controllers_path = ROOT.DS.'controllers'.DS.str_replace('controller', '', strtolower($class_name)).'class.php';
    $models_path = ROOT.DS.'models'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'class.php';

    if(file_exists($lib_path)){
        require ($lib_path);
    }
    elseif (file_exists($controllers_path)){
        require_once ($controllers_path);
    }
    elseif (file_exists($models_path)){
        require_once ($models_path);
    }
    else{
            throw new Exception('Failed to load class : '.$class_name);
        }
}
```

Here is my code uploaded on cloud9 https://ide.c9.io/hunteelar/my-mvc

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: update your htaccess code

Comment: @Bhavik Patel I posted the code

Comment: @saurabhkamble i dont know what is wrong with my .htaccess code above ?

Comment: change `$lib_path = ROOT.DS.'lib'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'class.php';` to `$lib_path = ROOT.DS.'lib'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'.class.php';` you forgot to mention .(dot) with file name

Comment: @ChetanAmeta i changed it to '.class.php ' but now it's giving me this error :Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/config.class.php on line 14

Comment: check code of config class. `$setting` is protected variable and you are trying to use it as static variable in `get` function and also you are using `$setting` as function with () braces, not as array [] in get function

Answer (score 0):

I think you already solved this. But the problem is with the initialization of your code.

```
$controllers_path = ROOT.DS.'controllers'.DS.str_replace('controller', '', strtolower($class_name)).'class.php';
```

should actually be:

```
$controllers_path = ROOT.DS.'controllers'.DS.str_replace('controller', '', strtolower($class_name)).'.controller.php';
```

Also

```
$models_path = ROOT.DS.'models'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'class.php';
```

Should be

```
$model_path = ROOT.DS.'models'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'.php';
```

In case it may help someone else.